# How to get the file's DocComment?

Tags: php, string, parsing, documentation

The file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Title
 *
 *  Description
 *  bla bla..
 *
 *  @since 1.0
 *  @author lolcat
 */





/**
 *  Some class..
 *
 *  @since 1.0
 */
class BlaBla{

}
..
```

I want to get the first DocComment from it. Is it possible with PHP?

Reflection seems to have such a feature, but it only works for classes or functions, not files :(

Comment: you just want the first block in a php variable ?

Comment: yes. I already have a DocComment (stole from SAMI) parser function, which I'll use to extract some tags I need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a basic extension for that kind of things. It's called [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

Use [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) function.

Every token in returned array has it's id. There are global constants that define them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php.

If you use PHP >= 5.3:

```
$s = file_get_contents('tokexample.php');

$docblock = reset(array_filter(token_get_all($s), 
                  function($item) { 
                      return $item[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT; 
                  }));

echo $docblock[1];

/**
 *  Title
 *
 *  Description
 *  bla bla..
 *
 *  @since 1.0
 *  @author lolcat
 */
```

Else:

```
function filter($item) {
    return $item[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT;
}

$docblock = reset(array_filter(token_get_all($s), "filter"));

echo $docblock[1];
```

Comment: This will return all "comments" (//, /*) in the file. Interesting to know how to determine the docblock.

Comment: thanks! I'm reading only the first 2K with fread($file, 4096) and then get the tokens. should be faster :P Also I'm breaking the for loop at the first found T_DOC_COMMENT bc I only need the first one